# automatic emails from user account database

Tags: php, mysql, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a database full of user accounts and other information that is linked to those user accounts.  I would like to offer the users the ability to setup automatic emails which notify them that new data has been added to various tables that are linked to their account.

I am not looking for full blown out code, but a point in the right direction here.  I have been searching and reading for the last day and have seen many different opinions on this.

The objective is a user will define an email address and rate at which to check for new data.  For instance they supply test@test.com and 15 minutes.  Once this is done I want to check if new data has been added to their account every 15 minutes, and if so, alert them via email. I have no problems writing the actual code to do this just not sure the 'correct' way to approach it as far as scheduling and automation of the script.

- MySQL take scheduler - I cannot use this as it is more than strictly db operations.  I need to actually run php code (sending the email and other stuff) on a scheduled basis rather than just perform operations in the db.
- Cronjob - I could make this work, however, it would be ONE cron job that checks EVERY user in my database and would have to check at the lowest interval I offer my users (1 minute).  Of course, my initial query on the database would only return those that it actually needs to check (where current timestamp is > last alert timestamp + rate seconds)  I would think running this script on the entire user set of my database every minute would be a performance issue, especially as the user base grows.  With this option there would also need to be some file locking on the script I would think to prevent it from running multiple times.
- Software side - as the database is tied to software the user installs on their computer I could also have the software 'hit' the php script I create at the user defined rate interval.  If they set it to 15 minutes then it would hit the script every 15 minutes to check.  This would work also, but as the user base grows this is an extreme number of hits to the same page fairly often as each user account would be doing so at their interval setup, however, it would also only happen when the software is running for that user which would cut down on that number.

With that said, any recommendations?  Positives, negatives, for and against one method over the other or some other suggestion I have not come across yet?

Comment: people will feel easy to answer if you breif things up with the code that you have tried

Comment: If you read what I posted it is explained... like I said, I have zero problems writing the code.

Comment: wht is the part u wnt to get right? is it the cron or the query that will check 15 min interval ?

Comment: I want to be pointed in the right direction on how to approach it.  I have no problems creating crons either... I pointed out some of my thoughts on different options above.  This number of users in this database will be growing on a daily basis so I am looking into the future / long term as the best way to implement the automation without having problems down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the software side, your check needs to be driven server side.

I would use a cron job to do that. You are right, you will have only 1 cron job for all your user, but it is not a problem.

Imagine you have a cron job running every minutes. In the cron job, the first task will be to find users you need to verify if something happened for them according to the current time and the user periodical check choice. Sometimes, you will not find users to check, sometimes yes. Even if you have plenty of users, it will not take long time. Then, loop only through the users which need to be checked and send e-mail if needed.

Comment: ... and you don't think there will be an issue with this?  This is an article I came across last night and some of the problems they had with this approach which is why I held off on it - https://medium.com/@sunils34/the-cronjob-that-generates-4-million-a-year-4540b0cde584

Comment: Why don't you fill another table (or an message queue outside the database) with the messages to be sent? I.e. via triggers or even the event scheduler. The cronjob only processes this table.

Comment: The query to find users to verify must be quick. After that, if you need to verify 5M of users because your 5M of users ask to verify their accounts every minutes, yes it will be a problem in this case AND in every others cases. I don't know what load you plan for your website, but the verification about new events for 1 user in your database should based on indexed timestamps and be quick.

Comment: @VMai - that is an interesting idea.  As the alerts are added to the db... if the user is to be notified I add it to a txt file which is the current message queue for all the users in the db.  The cron then doesn't touch the db at all... it just reads the txt file, processes it, and sends them out.  Off the top of my head, read the txt file and extract the ones that need to be sent into another file or array and at the same time delete them from the original txt file... the new file/array is the messages that are sent out and the original is there for additions and the next time.

Comment: @VMai - actually the way I have the site setup each user has a specific 'file location' on the server.  I use this for user specific files, downloads, etc.  I could easily create an alert queue file for each user in this area.  The cron would then process all of these txt files and send out which ones are needed.  I wonder what the performance of something like this would be?  Anyone care to chime in on that?

Comment: @user756659 Try it. You can separate the concerns: a) database server, b) processing in the api, http server c) mailserver if needed.

Comment: @user756659 I always avoid the usage of an external text file. You have a database, use it. If you need to execute several queries in your tables to know if an e-mail must be send to a user, the VMai's concept can be a good implementation. But the triggers should add entries in a specific table, not into a file. Therefore, you can keep traces that an e-mail has been sent to a user using status and timestamps fields.

Comment: Testing this out now... as alerts come in I check to see if the user wants notification of it.  If so, I add the alert to a new alerts_queue table including its timestamp.  My cron query basically runs through the alerts_queue table and returns only those values `WHERE alerts.last_email + (alerts.email_rate * 60) < UTC_TIMESTAMP()`.  last_email is a timestamp of the last email sent for that user... email_rate is a value in minutes of the minimum amount of time between emails.  Query should be fine running every minute, but might need to send emails with Amazon SES or it might bog my server.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not to make it time based but send an email every time there's something new. Analogous to receiving an email when somebody comments your post on social networks. Not sure if that's possible with your business requirements. Observer design pattern springs to mind, although there are many ways.

Comment: This was my original plan, but it could very easily send out hundreds or more emails to any specific user at once.  I decided on a user selected rate to allow them to cut down on how frequently they receive emails (I would queue the notifications and send them all at once).  Rate is set at 15 minutes, email sent... 50 alerts come in for the user in the next 15 minutes and are queued until it is allowed to email again)... at this time it would send a single email with the 50 queued alerts in it.